# Realm React Native partial sync

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm using react native realm new version 2.3.0, and subsribeToObjects was removed and changed it to Realm.Results.subscribe().

Is there any workaround on how to use Realm.Results.subscribe()?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to get change notifications? If so...

```
let objs = realm.objects('Object')
objs.addListener(() => {
 //...
})
```

https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#collection-notifications

If you are trying to subscribe to partial sync results:

```
let obs = realm.objects('Object')
let subscription = objs.subscribe()
subscription.addListener((state) => {
  //...
})
```